# How to use raw socket to send udp packet to local process with fake source ip and port

Tags: linux, sockets, raw

As the title said. I want to construct udp packets and send them to local process which  has bound specific port. I want to make the process believe in that the packets are from other host(such as 8.8.8.8). What arguments should I pass to socket() and sendto()?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/packit might be helpful

Comment: @EmployedRussian this is a commandline program. I want to use Raw Socket api

Comment: "I want to use raw api" -- if you can achieve desired effect with an external program, it's easy to discover what APIs it uses by looking at `strace` or the source of that program.